# Spawn instances one by one in AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

How to spawn instances one by one using AWS CloudFormation Templates ? Right now all the instances are spawned at the same time. Following are the values that i have used (min|default|max):

- MinInstances : 1 | 1 | 25
- MaxInstances : 2 | 4 | 26
- DesiredInstances: 1 | 3 | 25

With the above configuration all the 3 nodes are spawned at the same time. I want them to be spawned sequentially i.e one after the other.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can see if [DependsOn Attribute](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) of CF can solve your issue. I have not used this attribute before.

Comment: but what will it depend on ? here is my template [link](http://pastebin.com/VdfZzaK4)